# Conflicto entre plugin y Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Estoy intentando utilizar este plugin para animar un Dropdown:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Multi-level-jQuery-Dropdown-Plugin/

Estoy utilizando Bootstrap tambien y el problema que estoy teniendo es que me modifica otros dropdowns que tengo y yo solo quiero el efecto en 1 dropdown en particular. ¿Como puedo solucionar este problema de compatibilidad o que otro plugin que no de problemas de conflicto puedo usar?. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que se trata de jquery y que aunque no hay código se entiende el uso de la librería, cuando se selecciona por elementos, se hace de esta forma:

```
$('select, ul').dropdown();
```

Es por eso que funciona para todos, porque aplica ese efecto para todos los select y todos los ul. Lo que necesitas es llamarlos pero solo por el ID del elemento en los que quieras aplicarlo. Por ejemplo:

```
$('#idSelect, #idUl').dropdown();
```

Esos vendrían a ser solo los id's de esos elementos particulares que quieras que tengan ese efecto.

Otra opción también sería hacerlo por clases:

```
$('select.miClase').dropdown();
```

Y le das el nombre de la clase a ese elemento select en el que quieras dar el efecto.